# Why can't Horde cannot find files in php folder?

Tags: php, horde

I have Horde installed on a RHEL 6 machine running Apache.
When I launch it, I get a

> "PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Horde/Autoloader/Default.php'

My files are loaded at `/var/www/horde/`
My php files are loaded at '/usr/share/pear/'

The file that it's looking for is at '/usr/share/pear/Horde/Autoloader/Default.php'

My `httpd.conf` file points to `/var/www/horde`

When I put in localhost it finds my index.php in the horde folder.

How do I configure it so that the files in the php folder can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I added a line to my php.ini which set the include_path which seems to fix my problem.